How can close the terminal after starting sleek?
I have installed sleek with snap:
snap list  sleek
Name   Version  Rev   Tracking       Publisher  Notes
sleek  2.0.13   1218  latest/stable  ransome    -

Run it with snap:
snap run sleek


sleek started, i want to run it on background.
snap run sleek &
snap run sleek 1>/dev/null  2>&1

Both of them can start the sleek ,but i want the terminal closed after starting sleek .


Have you tried snap run sleek & exit ?

Philippe please write it as a formal answer and give some explanation ,i give you all the bonus.

When we launch a command in the background with ampersand (&), the shell session stays on, one needs to explicitly call exit:
snap run sleek &
exit


You can try this.
Create a script runsleek.sh:
snap run sleek &
disown
exit

Then make the script executable and run it:
chmod +x runsleek.sh
./runsleek.sh


you can use nohup to run the app in the background and does not exit it after exiting the terminal.
nohup sleek & exit

